# Angular evaluating directive from template referenced input

Tags: angular

I would expect the simple code to result in the button being disabled until the text length is no longer less than 3. However it does not seem to evaluate correctly as it stays disabled regardless of the input.

```
<input type="text" #myTextInput>
<button [disabled]="myTextInput.value.length < 3">Click me</button>
```

Comment: any exceptions in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could work, but since no event are sent, angular is not trying to check any change on the page. You can for exemple add (change)="aUselessMethod()" to your input and you will see that the code is working as expected.

Anyway I can't see a situation where you will need to get the input value like this.

Comment: I don't want the button to be clickable unless a user has entered at least 3 characters. I'll try your code today, thanks

Comment: Yep this is a common case, but normally you don't do it throught  #myTextInput,  you normally declare a [(ngModel)]  or a formControlName (when using formGroup) to bind the value